# bigquery command line to execute multiple queries in a single sql file

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way where I can execute multiple multi-line queries in a single sql file using bq command line?

I have tried the single line query and was successful but when I tried multi-line query, it returns an error.

```
test_query1.sql
==================
select 1+2;
select 3+4;
==================

command:
for /f "tokens=*" %A in (C://test/test_query1.sql) do bq query --use_legacy_sql=false %A
```

this runs the 2 queries separately.

But if I have this:

```
test_query1.sql
==================
select variable
from table1;

select var
from table2;
==================

command:
for /f "tokens=*" %A in (C://test/test_query1.sql) do bq query --use_legacy_sql=false %A
```

This runs "select variable" only then returns an error. Then it runs the "from table1" and returns an error and so on. How do I make sure that it reads the whole script until the ";" ?

Comment: Which error you get while executing test_query1 ?

Comment: Sorry the 1st line will return a success. But the 2nd and 3rd line returns an error.
It will process the "select var" only and returns this error:

..\Google\Cloud SDK>bq query --use_legacy_sql=false Select var
Error in query string: Error processing job
'ds-00-191017:bqjob_r6b1709be6304a11b_0000016c2d8888ca_1': Unrecognized name:
var at [1:8]

Then it processes the "from table2" and returns the same error.

Comment: It's doable, but I wouldn't advise putting different SQL statements in a SQL file. Keep them seperate for easier maintainability and debugging purposes. Name the file per use/business case and put it in source control. Also, consider using Cloud Build to execute your queries.

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (Beta now), you can just run the whole .sql file with one command:

```sql
test_query1.sql
==================
select variable
from table1;

select var
from table2;
==================
```

```
Command:
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < test_query1.sql
```